# You tried to create a weekly trigger, but did not specify which day in the week

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger for every week.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .everyWeeks(1)
  .create();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried specifying a day in the week using the onWeekDay() method? For example:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY)
  .everyWeeks(1)
  .create();
```

Adding a time of day using atHour() might also be required.